# How to make check matrix H when you have generator matrix (algorithm)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, algorithms, finite-fields

It's all built on top of python numpy lib. So we have a class finite field and get access to elements of field like Finite_field[index_of_element]. Elements of field are numpy matrices(ndarray). For a linear code it's given matrix G so G can be generated. And our G is ndarray of nrarrays. It think it's legal in numpy.

But to get H matrix we should 'solve' G matrix as $GH ^ \intercal = 0$. And numpy provides a solution you say as some function. But we can not divide in our class.

Any ideas?

Also if you have programmed codes in different environment and could recommend something it will be very appreciated. Cause I've heard about sympy, sage, etc., but thought that numpy will be great for such a task.

Thank you!

Comment: Nope. G is Generator matrix https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_matrix
I want to find H https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity-check_matrix. Elements of matrices are finite field elements but matrices are not square matrices.

Comment: ok https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity-check_matrix (and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_code#Construction_of_G_and_H ) seem to be quite explicit on how to generate $H$, so where is the problem ?

Comment: I do not understand how to do it. And this is not exactly that kind of linear code. Also how make standard form of G in numpy?

Comment: to be clear, is it about the maths, or about programming that you have some problems ? (I'd say both)

Comment: To be honest, I do not understand why this works for any linear code. I have  different(no Hamming) one. Ok, we can swap rows or columns in G. But why H has such a 'type'?  
Since that it's not too hard to swap some columns in matrix, make another matrix by appending matrices.  I think it can be done with some efforts.

Comment: It works because $G$ has $I$ as a submatrix : $xG = (x,xP)$  so $x\,G\, (-P^T,I)^T = (x,xP)\,(-P^T,I)^T  =   - xP +  xP = 0$

Answer (score 1):

You can form a generator matrix $G=(I\mid A)$ where $I$ is the identity matrix, by row eliminiation (and eventually by column permutations). Then as said, $H=(-A^T\mid I)$ is a parity check matrix, since $GH^T=0$.